# appending image tag in jquery not working(Update:need to prepend td)

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am writing jquery to append a td element and then add image tag to the td. But this is not working if i add src attribute to the image tag. Please find the code below.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dlglobal.dl.com/Admin/IT/operations/Documents/jquery.SPServices-0.5.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
//alert("alert test");
/*$Textsql = $("td.ms-vb2:contains('Budakov')"); 
$Textsql.css("background-color", "#461B7E"); */


$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetListItems",
  async: false,  
  listName: "OnCallList",

  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    //alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
$("#ctl00_m_g_87fe292c_7976_4ad4_bf5c_3c1ecf08b2d8_AdvancedDataGrid tr:first").append("<th></th>");

    $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=z:row]").each(function() {     

     var TextList=$(this).attr("ows_Title");
     $Textsql = $("td.ms-vb2:contains('" + TextList.toString() + "')");

     $Textsql.parent().prepend("<td class='ms-vb2'><img src='http://dlglobal.dl.com/Admin/IT/operations/PublishingImages/OnCall.png' /></td>");  });
}
});
});
</script>
```

UPDATE:

Thanks for all yor help. My requrirements got changed and I would like to prepend the image now instead of append. But my image is moving all the columns to the right. How to add image to only matching rows but not moving other columns to right. Iam attaching my screenshot here. Please help me.[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the code you used to add the `src` attribute?

Comment: In the code snippet you gave, the src attibute is never set. At this point, there is no reason why the navigator might show anything.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about the jQuery.SPServices module

Comment: I have updated my code to reflect the src attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is accurate replace the last string with this:

```
"<td><img src='/admin/PublishingImages/bulb.PNG' /></td>"
```

You had an issue with quotes.

Comment: It was very quick. Thank you so much. It worked.Sometimes small things take so much time.

Answer (score 0):

you could try it that way:

```
$Textsql.parent().append($('<td/>').append($('<img/>',{'src':'image.jpg'})));
```